# Entering wrong input gives nullpointer instead of errorHandling

Tags: spring-boot, error-handling

I have an app where you can add birdspecies to a list via form. The form automaticly checks for wrong or empty input and so far it works:
[image]

So when i click the button with wrong input, the page will show again with the correct errormessage.  Everything works fine except when at the field: "Year of discovery" i put letters instead of numbers, instead of showing the typemismatch error, the app crashes because of a nullpointer exception and i can't seem to figure out why it works for the other errors but not for the typeMisMatch.
Please don't refer me to the "What is a nullpointer and how do i fix it" page "because it is of no help.

Here is my controllercode:

```
@PostMapping(value="/{locationName}/addBirdSpecie")
public String onSubmit (
        
        @Valid BirdSpecie birdSpecie,
        BindingResult result, Model model,
        @PathVariable("locationName")String locationName)
{
    
    /* this is where the nullpointer happens (birdSpecie = null)*/
    yearValidation.validate(birdSpecie,result);
    if(result.hasErrors()) {
        return "addSpecie";
    }else {
        BirdSpotLocation birdSpotLocation = spottedBirdService.findByName(locationName).get();
    birdSpotLocation.increaseBirdSpot(birdSpecie);
    model.addAttribute("location", birdSpotLocation);
    return "birdsList";
    }
    
}
```

here is the model class for the birdSpecie:

```java
public class BirdSpecie {
    @NotEmpty
    private String name;
    
    @NotNull
    @Min(value=1250, message="{validation.Min.message}")
    private Integer yearOfDiscovery;
    
    @NotEmpty
    @Pattern(regexp= "^[A-Z]{1,2}[0-9]{3}$", message="{validation.Pattern.message}")
    private String code;
```

here is my jsp file:

```html
 <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
        pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags" prefix="spring"%>
<%@taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>
<%@taglib prefix = "form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    <meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
    <spring:url value="/css/style.css" var="urlCss"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="${urlCss}" type="text/css" />
    <title>Create a new bird Specie</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <h1>Create new bird specie:  </h1>
    <form:form method="post" action="addBirdSpecie" modelAttribute="birdSpecie">
    <spring:url value="/birdspotting/" var="showLocation" />
    <div>
    <p>
    Specie: <form:input path="name" size="25"/>
    <form:errors path="name" cssClass="error"/>
    <br>
    </p>
    <p>
    Year of discovery: <form:input path="yearOfDiscovery" size="25"/>
    <form:errors path="yearOfDiscovery" cssClass="error"/>
    <br>
    </p>
    <p>
    Books of birds code: <form:input path="code" size="25"/>
    <form:errors path="code" cssClass="error"/>
    <br>
    </p>

    <input type="submit" value="Spot new bird"/> 
    </div>

    </form:form>


    </body>
</html>
```

end here is the message for the typemismatch(alongside the other errormessages)

```
NotEmpty= This input may not be empty
NotNull= This input may not be empty
Pattern = Code should start with one or two capital letters [A-Z] followed by 3 digits
validation.futureYear.message = Birds can not be discovered in the future
typeMismatch.birdSpecie.yearOfDiscovery = The year may only contain digits
```

Edit:

Here is the yearValidator code:

```java
public class YearValidation implements Validator {

    @Override
    public boolean supports(Class<?> clazz) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return BirdSpecie.class.isAssignableFrom(clazz);
    }

    @Override
    public void validate(Object target, Errors errors) {
        BirdSpecie birdSpecie = (BirdSpecie) target;
        
        if(birdSpecie.getYearOfDiscovery()!=null && birdSpecie.getYearOfDiscovery() > Year.now().getValue()) {
            errors.rejectValue("yearOfDiscovery", "validation.futureYear.message");
        }
        
    }
}
```

The stacktrace:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "domain.BirdSpecie.getYearOfDiscovery()" because "birdSpecie" is null
   at validator.YearValidation.validate(YearValidation.java:22) ~[classes/:na]
   at com.birdSpotting.BirdspottingController.onSubmit(BirdspottingController.java:66) ~[classes/:na]
   at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
   at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
   at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
   at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564) ~[na:na]
   at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:190) ~[spring-web-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
   at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:138) ~[spring-web-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
   at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:105) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
   at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:878) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
   at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:792) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
   at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
   at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1040) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
   at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:943) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
   at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
   at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:909) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
   at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:652) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:4.0.FR]
   at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
   at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:733) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:4.0.FR]
   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
   at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
   at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:320) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.4.RELEASE.jar:5.3.4.RELEASE]
   at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:126) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.4.RELEASE.jar:5.3.4.RELEASE]
   at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:90) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.4.RELEASE.jar:5.3.4.RELEASE]
   at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.4.RELEASE.jar:5.3.4.RELEASE]
   at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:118) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.4.RELEASE.jar:5.3.4.RELEASE]
   at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.4.RELEASE.jar:5.3.4.RELEASE]
   at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:137) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.4.RELEASE.jar:5.3.4.RELEASE]
   at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.4.RELEASE.jar:5.3.4.RELEASE]
   at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:111) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.4.RELEASE.jar:5.3.4.RELEASE]
   at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.4.RELEASE.jar:5.3.4.RELEASE]
   at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:158) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.4.RELEASE.jar:5.3.4.RELEASE]
   at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.4.RELEASE.jar:5.3.4.RELEASE]
   at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.4.RELEASE.jar:5.3.4.RELEASE]
   at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.4.RELEASE.jar:5.3.4.RELEASE]
   at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.ui.DefaultLogoutPageGeneratingFilter.doFilterInternal(DefaultLogoutPageGeneratingFilter.java:52) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.4.RELEASE.jar:5.3.4.RELEASE]
   at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
   at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.4.RELEASE.jar:5.3.4.RELEASE]
   at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.ui.DefaultLoginPageGeneratingFilter.doFilter(DefaultLoginPageGeneratingFilter.java:216) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.4.RELEASE.jar:5.3.4.RELEASE]
   at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.4.RELEASE.jar:5.3.4.RELEASE]
   at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:200) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.4.RELEASE.jar:5.3.4.RELEASE]
   at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.4.RELEASE.jar:5.3.4.RELEASE]
   at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:116) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.4.RELEASE.jar:5.3.4.RELEASE]
   at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.4.RELEASE.jar:5.3.4.RELEASE]
   at org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CsrfFilter.doFilterInternal(CsrfFilter.java:141) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.4.RELEASE.jar:5.3.4.RELEASE]
   at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
   at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.4.RELEASE.jar:5.3.4.RELEASE]
   at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doHeadersAfter(HeaderWriterFilter.java:92) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.4.RELEASE.jar:5.3.4.RELEASE]
   at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:77) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.4.RELEASE.jar:5.3.4.RELEASE]
   at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
   at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.4.RELEASE.jar:5.3.4.RELEASE]
   at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:105) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.4.RELEASE.jar:5.3.4.RELEASE]
   at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.4.RELEASE.jar:5.3.4.RELEASE]
   at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:56) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.4.RELEASE.jar:5.3.4.RELEASE]
   at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
   at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.4.RELEASE.jar:5.3.4.RELEASE]
   at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:215) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.4.RELEASE.jar:5.3.4.RELEASE]
   at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:178) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.4.RELEASE.jar:5.3.4.RELEASE]
   at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:358) ~[spring-web-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
   at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:271) ~[spring-web-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
   at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) ~[spring-web-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
   at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
   at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
   at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
   at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) ~[spring-web-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
   at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
   at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
   at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
   at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:541) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
   at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
   at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
   at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
   at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
   at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:373) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
   at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
   at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:868) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
   at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1589) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
   at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
   at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1130) ~[na:na]
   at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:630) ~[na:na]
   at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
   at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:832) ~[na:na]
```

Comment: Show the code of `yearValidation.validate(birdSpecie,result);`

Comment: If you get an exception, which you do, it might be a good idea to add that stacktrace, fully!, to your question. That being said, your validator can result in a `NullPointerException` due to autoboxing `null` to an `int` value for comparing the year  . You return an `Integer` (object) while `Year.getValue()` returns an `int`. So before comparing it does `((int) null) > year.value)` casting a `null` to a primitive leads to a `NullPointerException`.

Comment: i added the stacktrace. But i still dont understand how i could fix this

Comment: Looks to me that you are missing `if (result.hasErrors()) {` in the beginning of your controller method.

Comment: It's there, below the yearvalidation.validate